# Add a suffix to each dataframe in a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list that contains several dataframes. I would like to add a suffix to each of the names of the dataframes, so that when I call the function

```
list2env()
```

and extract the dataframes their name has the suffix added before.
How can I do that?

**Sample Data**

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c(1,2,3)))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = c(1,2,3)))
lst <- list(df1,df2)
```

Comment: You can create a named list `list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to automatically get a `named` `list`, use `mget` with a `pattern` argument in the `ls`.  In the below code, we are getting the value of objects with names that start (`^`) with substring 'df' followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) till the end (`$`) of the string.

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^df\\d+$'))
```

Now, if we use `list2env` on the `list` created, it would update the same objects in the global environment

```
list2env(lapply(lst1, transform, new = V1 + 3), .GlobalEnv)
```

And if we need to create new objects, just change the name of the `lst1`

```
names(lst1) <- paste0(names(lst1), "_2018")
list2env(lapply(lst1, transform, new = V1 + 3), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Assuming I would like to add the suffix: '_2018' to the dataframes in the list, how could I do that? Do I need to use the function you mentioned when I create the list?

Comment: @Pietro Is it to add df1_2018, df2_2018 as names of list or the column names

Comment: @Pietro can you please check the updated coded.  Hope it helps

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks.
I used only the line: names(lst1) <- paste0(names(lst1), "_2018") and it worked fine